# c3 bar graph align tick values with non-centered ticks

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying to push the values on the x category axis to be on the sides of the bars, not in the middle. Apparently it is possible to put the ticks there, but can values go under the ticks as well?

```js
var chart;
chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.98 
        }
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: [10, 50, 100, 500, 2000, 5000],
        tick: {
          centered: false
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" class="c3" style="max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the prettiest answer, and the last label gets chopped off (you'll have to investigate c3's padding options), but these 2 lines after you've rendered the chart do the trick:

```
  // use c3's internal x scale to get the width of one bar
  var width = chart.internal.x(1) - chart.internal.x(0);
  // shuffle all the tick label tspans along by half a bar's width  
  d3.select(".c3-axis").selectAll(".tick text tspan").attr("dx", width/2);
```

```js
var chart;
chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.98 
        }
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: [10, 50, 100, 500, 2000, 5000],
        tick: {
          centered: false
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
  });

  var width = chart.internal.x(1) - chart.internal.x(0);
  d3.select(".c3-axis").selectAll(".tick text tspan").attr("dx", width/2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" class="c3" style="max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: Yup, adding  padding: {right: 15}, fixes the chopping issue